# In PostgreSQL how to retrieve column with special characters and alphabet

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to pull data from a column called file name in which users have to upload the file name with only numericals for eg: 245654, 346595 , 700542. But in few cases i have also noted users where using special characters and aplhabets for e.g. 245654 / Abc, 654658-cgds,78345|ghj. I need to extract all such entries where along with numericals such special characters and alphabets are also noted.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some similarities, they are quite different database products.

Comment: Postgres it is, i tagged redshift as well to know if in case i have to work on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use regex like here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE filename ~ '[^0-9]';
```

The above query will return any record whose file name has one or more non digit characters in it.

Comment: can we replace ~ with like ?

Comment: @AllanPhilip No, I don't think so, because Postgres' `LIKE` operator doesn't support regex.

Comment: Thank your solution it is perfectly working. Any idea about what can be used for the same in redshift ?

Comment: Use `WHERE REGEXP_COUNT(filename, '[^0-9]') > 0`

Comment: @dark_rider . . . Redshift supports `~`:  https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html.

Comment: @dark_rider Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is not an ongoing blog where you get to keep asking follow up questions.  You should ask a new question if you need help with Spark.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleise, i'll ask a new question for any other help. Cheers